# How to delete last item in list?

Tags: python, time, python-3.x

I have this program that calculates the time taken to answer a specific question, and quits out of the while loop when answer is incorrect, but i want to delete the last calculation, so i can call `min()` and it not be the wrong time, sorry if this is confusing.

```
from time import time

q = input('What do you want to type? ')
a = ' '
record = []
while a != '':
    start = time()
    a = input('Type: ')
    end = time()
    v = end-start
    record.append(v)
    if a == q:
        print('Time taken to type name: {:.2f}'.format(v))
    else:
        break
for i in record:
    print('{:.2f} seconds.'.format(i))
```

Answer (score 421, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, you can use the slicing notation to keep everything except the last item:

```
record = record[:-1]
```

But a better way is to delete the item directly:

```
del record[-1]
```

Note 1: Note that using record = record[:-1] does not really remove the last element, but assign the sublist to record. This makes a difference if you run it inside a function and record is a parameter. With record = record[:-1] the original list (outside the function) is unchanged, with del record[-1] or record.pop() the list is changed. (as stated by @pltrdy in the comments)

Note 2: The code could use some Python idioms. I highly recommend reading this:
[Code Like a Pythonista: Idiomatic Python](http://web.archive.org/web/20170316131253id_/http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html) (via wayback machine archive).

Comment: del record[-1] has side effects. This is a bad design and should be avoided if possible.

Comment: @Longurimont can you please explain what side effects does it have?

Comment: @M. Volf this is pretty well discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520492/difference-between-del-remove-and-pop-on-lists tl:dr only issue might be in a loop and you would have the same issues with any approach

Comment: @TheDavidFactor I don't see anything about `del x[-1]` there

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood @Logurimont's original comment, but anything inside a bracket is simply slice notation so I assumed the issue was with the del. using del was addressed in the accepted answer of the question I referenced. Slice notation is documented here: https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/brackets/slicing.html

Comment: @charlie parker setting a variable and popping the last element off the list is not declarative of what the effect you are trying to achieve (deleting the last element, not saving it for use elsewhere), and will typically also end up with an unused variable...

Comment: @DrCord what do you mean? It declares you want to remove the last element and then use it...I don't understand your point.

Comment: By setting a variable you are saying "I intend to use this". Most modern linters (code hinting) frowns on unused variables because they make your code less clear. Your code should reflect as close to what the intended effect is - you want to remove and discard the element not get and use the element - so `del` is a much better solution.

Answer (score 188):

you should use this

```
del record[-1]
```

The problem with

```
record = record[:-1]
```

Is that it makes a copy of the list every time you remove an item, so isn't very efficient

Comment: This is a better solution than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 158):

`list.pop()` removes and returns the last element of the list.

Comment: With the mention that it throws an `IndexError` if the list is empty. In case you don't want to have a try/except, there are better options.

Comment: @AdrianPop Would you mind sharing the better options in an answer? The solution `del record[-1]` throws an `IndexError`, too. Besides I think having an exception thrown is a good thing; if your program logic theoretically does not allow for an empty list you don't need a try/except, and if it gets empty nevertheless due to a bug, it's good to have the exception

Answer (score 14):

You need:

```
record = record[:-1]
```

before the `for` loop.

This will set `record` to the current `record` list but *without* the last item. You may, depending on your needs, want to ensure the list isn't empty before doing this.

Comment: Could you also use `record.pop()`? (NB: I am very new to python)

Comment: Yes, you could also use record.pop(). See http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: I put `record.pop()` at the end of the while loop, is that why it wouldn't work?

Comment: @CodeBeard, you _could_ use `pop` but it's not really necessary if you just want to throw the item away.

Comment: Make sure you're *not* assigning the value returned by pop() to record. Otherwise you're storing the last value of the list in record.

Comment: @paxdiablo, It's OK to slice empty lists :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo and Bastiano9 - thanks - is there a performance impact in not using the return?

Comment: @Samir, in my head you would use pop after the while loop when record is 'full' and you want to trim it. Sounds like record = record[:-1] is the more pythonic way.

Comment: @CodeBeard, remember that a slice is _copying_ that chunk of the list, so it's not very efficient. `pop` is ok, but `del` is even better.

Comment: @gnibbler so,slice is less efficient. How would one use `del` on the last element? `del list[:-1]` or `del list[len(list)-1)`?

Comment: @CodeBeard, close - `del record[-1]`

Answer (score 12):

just simply use `list.pop()`
now if you want it the other way use : `list.popleft()`

Comment: With the mention that it throws an `IndexError` if the list is empty. In case you don't want to have a try/except, there are better options.

Comment: For list, can use list.pop(-1)

Answer (score 10):

You must use *list, _ = list as in the following example

```
record = [1,2,3]
*record, _ = record
record
---
[1, 2]
```

Comment: This is indeed a very Pythonic way

Answer (score 3):

If you do a lot with timing, I can recommend this little (20 line) context manager:

- https://github.com/brouberol/timer-context-manager

You code could look like this then:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

from timer import Timer

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a, record = None, []
    while not a == '':
        with Timer() as t: # everything in the block will be timed
            a = input('Type: ')
        record.append(t.elapsed_s)
    # drop the last item (makes a copy of the list):
    record = record[:-1] 
    # or just delete it:
    # del record[-1]
```

---

Just for reference, here's the content of the [Timer](https://github.com/brouberol/timer-context-manager/blob/bdb24345b1c24264a982068b75cef211f4690959/timer.py) context manager in full:

```
from timeit import default_timer

class Timer(object):
    """ A timer as a context manager. """

    def __init__(self):
        self.timer = default_timer
        # measures wall clock time, not CPU time!
        # On Unix systems, it corresponds to time.time
        # On Windows systems, it corresponds to time.clock

    def __enter__(self):
        self.start = self.timer() # measure start time
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
        self.end = self.timer() # measure end time
        self.elapsed_s = self.end - self.start # elapsed time, in seconds
        self.elapsed_ms = self.elapsed_s * 1000  # elapsed time, in milliseconds
```

Comment: Actually this is the first 'time' program i've written, but when I get a little more familiar with the module, I'l take a look into it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of lists (*tracked_output_sheet* in my case), where you want to delete last element from each list, you can use the following code:

```
interim = []
for x in tracked_output_sheet:interim.append(x[:-1])
tracked_output_sheet= interim
```