# Access specific entries in a python tuple

Tags: python, tuples

In a python tuple I want to acces the first entry. I can do that by writing:

```
example_tuple[0]
```

Now this first entry is an array of float. From this array I want to get all entries except the last one. Like descibed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18169965/how-to-delete-last-item-in-list), I did this by writing:

```
example_array[:-1]
```

Now I want to stack these two features and I tried it with the following command:

```
example_tuple[0[:-1]]
```

This is producing the following error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

I'm not sure what's wrong as there is no integer involved in this.

Comment: try `example_tuple[0][:-1]`

Comment: @ShubhamShaswat Yes. This works perfect for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By typing:

```py
example_tuple[0[:-1]]
```

Python tries to compute what's inside the bracket first, that is `0[:-1]`. That explains the error:

```py
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

You are trying to access `0` as an array.

As @ShubhamShaswat said, to access an array within an array, you need to get the first one, and access the value you want in it:

```py
example_tuple = [[5.7, 2.9, 7.9], [0.1, 4.2], [1.2]]

### Using 2 steps ###
# temp_var equals [5.7, 2.9, 7.9]
temp_var = example_tuple[0]
# output: [5.7, 2.9]
print(temp_var[:-1])

### Which can be shortened in Python by assembling array access ###
# output: [5.7, 2.9]
print(example_tuple[0][:-1])
```