# Runtime difference between set.discard and set.remove methods in Python?

Tags: python, set

The [official Python 2.7 docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html) for these methods sounds nearly identical, with the sole difference seeming to be that `remove()` raises a KeyError while `discard()` does not.

I'm wondering if there is a difference in execution speed between these two methods. Failing that, is there any meaningful difference (barring KeyError) between them?

Comment: Related post on similar lines for list data structure - [Difference between del, remove and pop on lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11520492/465053)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Raising an exception in one case is a *pretty meaningful difference*. If trying to remove an element from a set that is not there would be an error, you better use `set.remove()` rather than `set.discard()`.

The two methods are identical in implementation, except that compared to [`set_discard()`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/1c3f8d044589/Objects/setobject.c#l1920) the [`set_remove()` function](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/1c3f8d044589/Objects/setobject.c#l1888) adds the lines:

```c
if (rv == DISCARD_NOTFOUND) {
    set_key_error(key);
    return NULL;
}
```

This raises the `KeyError`. As this is slightly more work, `set.remove()` is a *teeniest* fraction slower; your CPU has to do one extra test before returning. But if your algorithm *depends on the exception* then the extra branching test is hardly going to matter.

Answer (score 1):

I was curious about this as well and did a `timeit` test and it seems there's no difference at all ([see the results here](https://tio.run/##dZDBasMwDIbvfgrRS20IYWluYzv1tPtupRSTqKtZLBtZWVvGnj3TkpwG1Umy9Ov/rHyXS6J2mkLMiQUkRAxizpwidGkYsJOQqMDa3qeRBNmYgjJmeIWtJqcKPvFetNLCsqcPtM3THM5VEFTw/3VrzFBEFYejOSeGEwSCZaZ1zwY0pNH2glMzZvRiZ7O6D6Xz3FvCm9g/Y11XwQzkFuXugZIxpi98LFSk2ueM1NsYyErj4AXmbOecMZkDid28EbSAt4ysFiSlgmUvXH2BMqQrMsjFE6yg8P0z05RNrV@NSrNe0aqfO7zziEfnpukX)). Essentially, the best timings of 5 runs each of `discard` and `remove` were compared. This was repeated 3 times and `remove` was slower than `discard` once and `discard` was slower twice.

The code used for the experiment is as follows.

```py
import timeit
from collections import Counter

setup = 'set_, keys = set(range(1000000)), iter(range(1000000))'

lst = []
for _ in range(3):
    t1 = timeit.repeat('set_.discard(next(keys))', setup)
    t2 = timeit.repeat('set_.remove(next(keys))', setup)
    lst.append(min(t1) < min(t2))

print("In 3 experiments, remove was slower than discard {} times".format(Counter(lst)[True]))
# In 3 experiments, remove was slower than discard 1 times
```