# Removing element in a list

Tags: python, list

```
list = [0, 1, 2, 8, 2, 9, 2]
```

Is there a way to remove the element `2`, exactly one time?

So you will get:

```
list = [0, 1, 2, 8, 9, 2]
```

I tried to work with `index()` but I didn't found it.

It can be a RANDOM `2`.

So I can't use `remove()` or `pop()` because it will not remove the number `2` on a random position.

Comment: could you explain how you got that output

Comment: Your intended output has the second `2` being removed, what criteria should decide which number is removed?

Comment: It deletes a random number '2' in the list. The output can be something else because there are three of them.

Comment: if the list can be random, why can't you use `remove`? It removes the first occurrence...

Comment: I'm sorry but your question is a bit confusing. Are you always going to remove a 2, or can it be a different number?

Comment: @Poonuts it can be different numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To randomly remove occurrence of `2`

**Notes:**

- we create a list of indexes of the number `2` i.e. `[i for i, j in enumerate(lst) if j == 2]`
- Using random module [choice method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306400/how-do-i-randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list-using-python) to get one index randomly from the index list
- list [pop method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520492/difference-between-del-remove-and-pop-on-lists)  or remove method it's up to your choice

**Code:**

```
import random
lst = [0, 1, 2, 8, 2, 9, 2]
lst.pop(random.choice([i for i, j in enumerate(lst) if j == 2]))
print lst
```

**output:**

```
[0, 1, 8, 2, 9, 2]
```

Comment: Thx, that was the thing I was looking for!

Comment: @Victor happy to help :)

Answer (score 6):

This works

```
list.remove(2)
```

> L.remove(value) -- remove first occurrence of value.
>
> Raises ValueError if the value is not present.

Comment: the OP says he doesn't want/cannot use `remove`

Comment: @Pynchia: The OP _believes_ he can't use `remove`.

Comment: ahahahahaha, yes, that is what I have told him, he can, since the list is randomly popoulated. Anyhow, better leave this awful question to somebody else. BTW I've removed my answer and upvoted this one

Comment: Your solution deletes the first element found. I need to delete a  RANDOM one.

Comment: @Victor You never told that it should be a random 2 in your question.

Comment: @Matthias Funny business.

Answer (score 1):

Use  `del` or `pop`

For example,

```
del list[2]
```

or

```
list.pop(2)
```

The difference between del and pop is that

`del` is overloaded.

for example, del a[1:3] means deletion of elements 1 and 3

Answer (score 0):

Note that you're shadowing the built-in `list`. Apart from that `index` works just fine:

```
>>> li = [0, 1, 2, 8, 2, 9, 2]
>>> li.pop(li.index(2))
2
>>> li
[0, 1, 8, 2, 9, 2]
```