# why dict does not have remove method?

Tags: python

I know python list has a remove() method, which remove the given object from the list.

```
aList = [123, 'xyz', 'zara', 'abc', 'xyz']
aList.remove('xyz')
```

I know that we can use del statement to delete an item from the list by offset:

```
del aList[-1]
```

I also know that we can use del statement to delete an item from the dictionary by key:

```
aDict = {'a':1, 'b':2 'c':3}
del aDict['a']
```

However, there is no remove() method for a dictionary, which I think is perfectly fine:

```
aDict.remove('a')
```

I guess one reason is that *remove()* does not save any typing than *del* statement for dictionary, so it is not necessary. Is this correct?

While for list, remove() combines "*search index by value*" and "*delete by index*" together, so it has to be there. Is this correct?

What are the other reasons if any?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `list.remove` makes a very strict guarantee - removing the **first** occurrence of a *value*. Now, the ordering in a `dict` is arbitrary - there is no "first".

Comment: So you mean apply remove() to dict is conceptually wrong because there is no "first" for dict. I like this.

Comment: It's just the first I could come up with. There are some other issues as well - `list` is pretty much fixed in size, so you can "guess" how long `remove` will take. In contrast, `dict` may be arbitrarily larger than it's data contained.  There are several instances where python avoids having interfaces that would imply quick performance, when they are in fact slow.

Comment: Why does `set` support `remove` method? Values also have no order in set.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at this question: [Difference between del, remove and pop on lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520492/difference-between-del-remove-and-pop-on-lists) : you'll note the main answer points out

> remove: removes the *first* matching *value*, not a specific index
>
> del:  removes a specific index
>
> pop: returns the removed element

So with a Dictionary it simply doesn't need a remove method as there can only be one instance of a key (they have to be unique) and `del` is sufficient.

Comment: Agreed. However @MisterMiyagi's answer is more close. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 3):

It does, it's just called [`pop`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop):

> pop(key[, default])
>   If key is in the dictionary, remove it and return its value, else return default. If default is not given and key is not in the dictionary, a KeyError is raised.

Comment: `dict.pop()` has a certain result though, which is what it's usually used for.

Comment: This does not really answer the question of why python does not have a dict.remove() function but does have a list.remove(). As pop is used for something different (and lists have both methods)

Comment: @JGreenwell Who said dicts and lists HAVE to have the same names for their methods?

Comment: @DeepSpace: Tim Peters alluded to it *"There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."* :) Really, for similar containers, is it unreasonable to expect methods which do the same thing to have the same name?

Comment: @SiHa According to that logic, neither should have `pop` or `remove` methods since the same can be done with `del`.

Comment: pop is still a method used to get and remove an element while remove simply removes the first instance of an element so again these are different methods

Comment: @DeepSpace Not true. `pop()` returns the removed item, `del()` doesn't. Anyway, I was only making a little joke.

Comment: Note that `pop` will remove by *key* identity, whereas `remove` will remove by *value* identity.

Comment: By the way, `copy`, `clear` and `pop` are actually the only not trivial methods that lists and dictionaries have in common: `li = set(dir(list)) ; 
dic = set(dir(dict)) ; 
print([method for method in li & dic if not method.startswith('_')]) ; ['copy', 'pop', 'clear']`

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries have `pop`, but not `remove`. Why not? Because `remove` finds the *first* matching *value* and removes it, and returns nothing. So in a dictionary:

```
{'a': 5, 'b': 5}
```

`dict.remove` ought to remove *values*. If I use `dict.remove(5)`, which key should it delete? Additionally this is not even very useful operation. If you need to remove a certain *value* from a dictionary, then you're using a wrong data structure.

---

```
dct.pop(key)
```

on the other hand, is not unlike

```
value = dct[key]
del dct[key]
return value
```

This can be contrasted with `pop` method of lists:

```
lst.pop(index)
```

is analogous to

```
value = lst[index]
del lst[index]
return value
```

that is, both of them operate using the same principle.