# randomly generating groups of people via values in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a program to randomly generate groups for the office scavenger hunt I am organizing so I wrote this simple code quickly to simulate picking names out of a hat but only more fairer, but not exactly sure why it isn't working, it doesn't return all the names, for example I have entered 6 names into the list but it only returns 4 of them like this:

```
Group 1 consists of;
Chris
Ryan
Paul
Group 2 consists of;
Alex
```

I don't have much experience with removing elements from a list so it could well just be me doing it wrong. Any insight would be helpful.

```
import random
participants=["Alex","Elsie","Elise","Kimani","Ryan","Chris","Paul"]
group=1
membersInGroup=3

for participant in participants:
    if membersInGroup==3:
        print("Group {} consists of;".format(group))
        membersInGroup=0
        group+=1
    person=random.choice(participants)
    print(person)
    membersInGroup+=1
    participants.remove(str(person))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between del, remove and pop on lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520492/difference-between-del-remove-and-pop-on-lists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is happening because you are mutating a list while iterating over it.  There are a few options for solving this.  One option that requires little modification to your existing code and thought process is to **mutate a copy of the list**, e.g. `participants[:]` makes a copy.

Using your code:

```
import random
participants=["Alex","Elsie","Elise","Kimani","Ryan","Chris","Paul"]
group=1
membersInGroup=3

for participant in participants[:]:               # only modification
    if membersInGroup==3:
        print("Group {} consists of;".format(group))
        membersInGroup=0
        group+=1
    person=random.choice(participants)
    print(person)
    membersInGroup+=1
    participants.remove(str(person))
```

Sample output:

```
Group 1 consists of;
Alex
Paul
Chris
Group 2 consists of;
Kimani
Elsie
Elise
Group 3 consists of;
Ryan
```

Comment: thanks that actually makes so much sense, its little things like that, that change things massively

Answer (score 2):

Although [pylangs' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40865330/randomly-generating-groups-of-people-via-values-in-a-list/40865509#40865670) will suffice, this is another approach to solve the problem:

```
import random
members = 3
participants=["Alex","Elsie","Elise","Kimani","Ryan","Chris","Paul"]
random.shuffle(participants)
for i in range(len(participants) // members + 1):
    print('Group {} consists of:'.format(i + 1))
    group = participants[i*members:i*members + members]
    for participant in group:
        print(participant)
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of list.  The code has the problem in line

`for participant in participants:`

Instead use

`for participant in participants[:]:`