# github3 0.9.6 TypeError:pop() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: python, github3.py

I am currently using github3.py version 0.9.6, and am receiving an error upon invoking the **github3.organization(login)** function:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.py", line 23, in <module>
    __main__()
  File "Main.py", line 19, in __main__
    Stats.git_auth(username, password, access_token)
  File "/Users/edigiovine/Repositories/GitMetrics/Stats.py", line 36,   in git_auth
    git_orgs(gh)
  File "/Users/edigiovine/Repositories/GitMetrics/Stats.py", line 49, in git_orgs
    org = gh.organization(rel_org)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/github3/github.py", line 971, in organization
    return Organization(json, self) if json else None
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/github3/orgs.py", line 236, in __init__
    super(Organization, self).__init__(org, session)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/github3/models.py", line 311, in __init__
    super(BaseAccount, self).__init__(acct, session)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/github3/models.py", line 77, in __init__
    super(GitHubCore, self).__init__(json)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/github3/models.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.etag = json.pop('ETag', None)
TypeError: pop() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
```

I was hoping I could receive some help with resolving this issue. Specifically, I am curious as to where the None comes from in the last call.

Thanks for any help in advance!

**EDIT1:** I am trying to invoke particular organizations based on a list of existing orgs provided by a user, which in my case is much smaller than the total list of organizations, so iterating over all organizations would not be a benefit to me in this case (which happens to be my default case if a list is not given).

Thanks again!

**EDIT2:** A sample of the code I am implementing, obviously trivial (cannot give private info):

```
# Defined username, password, access_token, and api_call_base in a
# config file, use them here to build the github object.
gh = github3.login(username, password, access_token, api_call_base)

# predefined_orgs_list is a list of the names of the organizations
# that are in focus for my project.
for needed_org in predefined_orgs_list:

    # This is the function that throws the error I am receiving.
    org = gh.organization(needed_org)

    # If above function works, then the following value should be
    # the same as in the predefined_orgs_list
    print org.login
```

**EDIT3:** I know that the gh.organization function is what is causing the problem in my code, as can be seen by the stack trace. What my question is pertaining to is the library for github3 and asking how I resolve/fix the pop() function in models.py, which is the function throwing the error.

**EDIT4:** I resolved this issue, thanks to pdb:
from walking through the code, I found that the url generation is dynamic based on the inputs given to the organization function.

Specifically, what I had was a default base url to our organizations that correctly gathered our organization data. What I needed to do was modify my code to use two different urls, based on the condition of being given a list of orgs vs. grabbing all orgs.

This issue is now resolved. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Can you provide code?

Comment: Giving one line of code and a traceback will not help. What is `login`?

Comment: Looks like something's getting a list where it expected a dict.

Comment: @soundslikeodd, sample code provided.

Comment: @Leb, unfortunately that is private info, so I can only give a sample snippet and hope there is a public account with multiple organizations for testing. If you know of any, please let me know, since that will help me ask these kinds of questions better since I could provide more context.

Comment: I am not sure this is relevant but it looks like `gh.organization()` takes the login name of the organization [doc](https://github3.readthedocs.io/en/develop/github.html#github3.github.GitHub.organization).  Not sure if the `predefined_orgs_list` is this.  You describe it as `list of the names of the organizations`.

Answer (score 10):

Just for the record, it also happens when you expect a dict and want to clear it using `.pop(key, None)` but use it on a list instead. For a list, `.pop()` always takes only one argument.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in your `org = gh.organization(needed_org)` line. Apparently `.organization()` method uses [`pop`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/tutorial/datastructures.html). Whatever `predefined_orgs_list` variable might be, looks like a list (from the name ...duh) of some sort.

However from the link above, `pop` takes an index not an item. This answer [Difference between del, remove and pop on lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520492/difference-between-del-remove-and-pop-on-lists) shown a great example of what `pop` is used for and compares it to other methods.