# How to remove short strings from a list which is a value of a dict

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

I want to make a function called `remove_short_synonyms()` which is passed a dict
as a parameter. The keys of the parameter dict are words and the
corresponding values are lists of synonyms. The function removes all the
synonyms which have less than 7 characters from each corresponding list
of synonyms.

If this is the dict:

```
synonyms_dict = {'beautiful': ['pretty', 'lovely', 'handsome', 'dazzling', 'splendid', 'magnificent']}
```

How can I get this as the output?

```
{'beautiful': ['dazzling', 'handsome', 'magnificent', 'splendid']}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think your question is more proper to be titled as *Remove values from a list* instead of *dict*.

You can use remove, del or pop to remove element in a python list.
[Difference between del, remove and pop on lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520492/difference-between-del-remove-and-pop-on-lists)

Or in a more pythonic way, i think, is

```
dict['beautiful'] = [item for item in dict['beautiful'] if len(item)>=7]
```

Comment: the answer from user1190882 is a more general solution for a dict object, instead of just a list object

Answer (score 2):

Make use of dict comprehension and list comprehension.

```
synonyms_dict = {'beautiful' : ['pretty', 'lovely', 'handsome', 'dazzling', 'splendid', 'magnificent']}
synonyms_dict = {k:[v1 for v1 in v if len(v1) >= 7] for k, v in synonyms_dict.items()}
print(synonyms_dict)

# {'beautiful': ['handsome', 'dazzling', 'splendid', 'magnificent']}

​
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `python>=3.x`, a more readable solution for a beginner would be:

```
synonyms_dict = {'beautiful' : ['pretty', 'lovely', 'handsome', 'dazzling', 'splendid', 'magnificent']}

new_list = []
for key,value in synonyms_dict.items():
   for i in range(len(value)):
      if len(value[i]) >= 7:
         new_list.append(value[i])

synonyms_dict['beautiful'] = new_list
print(synonyms_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that modifies the existing dictionary rather than replacing it. This can be useful if you have multiple references to the same dictionary.

```
synonyms_dict = {
    'beautiful' : ['pretty', 'lovely', 'handsome', 'dazzling', 'splendid', 'magnificent']
}

def remove_short_synonyms(d, minlen=7):
    for k, v in d.items():
        d[k] = [word for word in v if len(word) >= minlen]

remove_short_synonyms(synonyms_dict)
print(synonyms_dict)
```

**output**

```
{'beautiful': ['handsome', 'dazzling', 'splendid', 'magnificent']}
```

---

Note that this code *does* replace the existing lists in the dictionary with new lists. You *could* keep the old list objects, if you really need to do that, by changing the assignment line to

```
d[k][:] = [word for word in v if len(word) >= minlen]
```

although that will be *slightly* slower, and there's probably no reason to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
def remove_short_synonyms(self, **kwargs):

dict = {}
  word_list = []

  for key, value in synonyms_dict.items():
    for v in value:
      if len(v) > 7:
        word_list.append(v)
    dict[key] = word_list

  print dict


remove_short_synonyms(synonyms_dict)
```