# Removing a dictionary from a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I wanna remove a dictionary from a nested dictionary and I don't know how.
**From this dictionary:**

```
dict = {  
    'user': [
        {
            'firstName': 'john',
            'lastName': 'doe',
            'movieList': []
        },
        {
            'firstName': 'sarah',
            'lastName': 'doe',
            'movieList': []
        },
        {
            'firstName': 'john',
            'lastName': 'smith',
            'movieList': []
        },
        {
            'firstName': 'sarah',
            'lastName': 'smith',
            'movieList': []
        }
    ], 'movie': []
}
```

I want to remove:

```
{
    'firstName': 'john', 
    'lastName': 'doe', 
    'movieList': []
}
```

which has the **index 0**
I tried using delete but i get this error:

```
dict['user'][userId] TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: @FELASNIPER del dict['user'][userId] , i don't knwo something else what i could do

Comment: `dict['user']` returns a _list_ not a _dictionary_, thats what the error is trying to tell

Comment: Try `del d['user'][0]` where d is your dictionary.

Comment: Whay is the value of `userid`?

Answer (score 3):

First, I wouldn't name the dict "dict", use "d" or something else.

```
dict['user'].pop(0)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping

Comment: What is "userId"? I copied the code you supplied and it worked just fine for me.

Comment: i didn't change the data type of userId

Comment: now it works fine

Answer (score 0):

I would write a comment, but my reputation is too low. It seems like your variable userId might be a string instead of an integer. If this is the case, try converting userId to an int:

```
userId = int(userId)
```

Answer (score 0):

See this question for more info on `del` `pop` and `remove` [Difference between del, remove and pop on lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520492/difference-between-del-remove-and-pop-on-lists)

If you do not want to use the dictionary you are removing, I would use `del`, as below:

```
d = {'user': [{'firstName': 'john', 'lastName': 'doe', 'movieList': []},
              {'firstName': 'sarah', 'lastName': 'doe', 'movieList': []},
              {'firstName': 'john', 'lastName': 'smith', 'movieList': []},
              {'firstName': 'sarah', 'lastName': 'smith', 'movieList': []}], 'movie': []}

del d['user'][0]
```

This `[0]` is deleting the first index of the `list` stored as the value of the `'user'` key

If you are repeatedly deleting the first index of your list and your list is long, consider using a deque() instead, which has fast pops from either end:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque

Also, don't call your variables the same name as their types, aka don't call your dictionary variable dict

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
dict1 = {'user': [{'firstName': 'john', 'lastName': 'doe', 'movieList': []}, {'firstName': 'sarah', 'lastName': 'doe', 'movieList': []}, {'firstName': 'john', 'lastName': 'smith', 'movieList': []}, {'firstName': 'sarah', 'lastName': 'smith', 'movieList': []}], 'movie': []}
new_dict = {a:b[1:] if b else b for a, b in dict1.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'movie': [], 'user': [{'lastName': 'doe', 'movieList': [], 'firstName': 'sarah'}, {'lastName': 'smith', 'movieList': [], 'firstName': 'john'}, {'lastName': 'smith', 'movieList': [], 'firstName': 'sarah'}]}
```