# How to specify the duplicate value to remove in a list python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I was solving a coding problem on Codefights and I ALMOST solved it but, a problem in my code occured and I can't find a way to solve the problem.

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 6]
print(my_list.index(3))
```

Output : `2`

```
print(my_list[4])
```

Output : `3`
But, here's the problem, when I try to remove the 3 which lies on index 4, Python removes the 3 on the 2nd index, and I don't want this to happen.
For example:

```
my_list.remove(my_list[4])
print(my_list)
```

Output : `[1, 2, 4, 3, 6]`
I want to get the output as : `[1, 2, 3, 4, 6]`

This is not my actual code, but just an example. Please help me out if you can.

Comment: Convert into a set, all duplicate values are removed. my_set=set(my_list)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between del, remove and pop on lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520492/difference-between-del-remove-and-pop-on-lists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually the expected output. You should use `del` instead.

```
del my_list[4]
```

The reason it was not working is that using this line:

```
my_list.remove(my_list[4])
```

translates in this line:

```
my_list.remove(3)
```

since `my_list[4]` return 3, which will then delete first occurence of 3 in the list.