# python TypeError with lists

Tags: python, string, list, function, typeerror

Why am I getting the error *"TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"*? But if I change the values in the list to integers, wouldn't doing `items.remove(items[1])` just remove the item in index position 1?

```
def choose_item():
    pick = int(input("Enter what item number you want [1-20]: "))
    store_item(pick)
    while pick < 1 or pick > 20:
        print("Not Valid")
        pick = input("Enter what item number you want [1-20]: ")


def store_item(pick):
    items =['1','1','1','1','1','2','2','2','2','2','3','3','3','3','3','4','4','4','4','4','5','5','5','5','5','5','5','5','5','5','6','6','6','6','6','7','7','7','7','7','8','8','8','8','8','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','10','10','10','10','10','11','11','11','11','11','12','12','12','12','12','13','13','13','13','13','14','14','14','14','14','15','15','15','15','15','16','16','16','16','16','17','17','17','17','17','18','18','18','18','18','19','19','19','19','19','20','20','20','20','20']
    if pick == 1:
        items.remove(items['1'])

choose_item()
```

Comment: jpp I used it in an if statement not a loop?

Comment: woops.. Reopening.. Hints: fix your code indentation, list indexing is via integers only, `list.remove` is in place. Your functions do not return anything as they have no `return` statements.

Comment: What do you expect `items['1']` to be?

Comment: Patrick Haugh items['1'] could correlate to coca cola for example in a vending machine. So when someone chooses 'item 1', it removes it

Comment: What is your question here? What do you want to know/achieve?

Comment: Thomas Why am I getting the error "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"?

Comment: Because you're using a string to index a list, which doesn't make any sense? What did you expect `items['1']` to do?

Comment: The error message can't be clearer: "list indices (like `k` in `[1,2,3][k]`, `"hey".split()[k]`) __must__ be of type `int`, and not anything else (not `str`, not `float`, not `list`, not `tuple`, _only_ `int`)". Are _all_ the indices used in your code of type `int`, especially the `'1'` in `items['1']`?

Comment: Aran-Fey so if i change all of the values in the list to integers. How would i be able to remove item number 1 from the list when someone picks item 1?

Comment: [How do I remove an element from a list by index in Python?](//stackoverflow.com/q/627435)

Comment: Also, nobody asked you to change the strings in the list to integers. We're talking about *indexing* the list with strings. This is ok: `your_list = ['1', '2']`. This is not: `your_list['1']`.

Comment: You'll probably also want to convert the input strings to integers? pick = int(input("Enter wh...[1-20]: "))

Comment: Forcetti Thank you! And then I had to do items.remove(1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a string as an integer here items.remove(items['1']), remove does not work like that.
Check this [Difference between del, remove and pop on lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520492/difference-between-del-remove-and-pop-on-lists)

Comment: Please mark this answer by @E.Serra as correct, if it solved your problem. Thank you!

Comment: You commented saying thanks that solved my problem, then removed comment, edited post etc.
It is fine, you realised on your own.