# Variable type is list but python says object type float does not have an attribute len

Tags: python-3.x

I am using Python 3 and the code is as follows

```
# Uses python3
import sys

def get_optimal_value(capacity, weights, values):
    value = 0.
    left_space=capacity
    vpw=[]
    for i in range (0,len(weights)-1):
        print (i)
        vpw.append(values[i]/weights[i])
    vpw_s=[]
    v_s=[]
    w_s=[]
    k=0
    vpw=list(vpw)
    print (type(vpw))
    while (len(vpw) > 0):
        j = vpw.index(max(vpw))
        vpw_s.append(vpw[j])
        v_s.append(values[j])
        w_s.append(weights[j])
        vpw=vpw.pop(j)
        k=k+1

    for i in range (0, len(w_s)-1):
        if (left_space> 0):
            w_u=min(w_s[i],left_space)
            value=value+w_u*vpw_s[i]

    # write your code here

    return value

if __name__ == "__main__":
    opt_value = get_optimal_value(10, [3,4,1], [10,12,80])
    print("{:.10f}".format(opt_value))
```

This gives an error -

```
<class 'list'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/main.py", line 35, in <module>
    opt_value = get_optimal_value(10, [3,4,1], [10,12,80])
  File "/home/main.py", line 16, in get_optimal_value
    while (len(vpw) > 0):
TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

Is the variable `vpw` not of the type list ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not when you first execute the `while`, but the second time. You have inside the loop:

```
    vpw=vpw.pop(j)
```

But, the [return value from `pop()`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/list/pop.html) is actually the element that you popped, and the list is modified in place, so you change `vpw` from a list to a float, thus the second time you execute the `while` you are trying to do `len()` on a float. The simple fix is just to delete the assignment:

```
    vpw.pop(j)
```

Comment: @user2778617 Please mark the answer as Accepted if it helped you - click the greyed tick at the left of the question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not when you do the first iteration but rather the second and onwards, where you say `vpw=vpw.pop(j)`, `pop` returns the value from that index, and deltes from the list, therefore vpw is now a float. You can try this by putting the print type inside the while loop. I recommend reading this, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11520540/10030086), to see what you are trying to go for, I believe you need `vpw.remove(max(vpw)`.