# How to use list.remove(value)/ list.pop(value) in python using indirect values in python

Tags: python, list

for example i have a list

```
mylist=[[1,2],[5,8],[-9,2],[0,-9],[4,0],[0,-4],[-1,-1]]
```

to remove [-9,2] is by

```
mylist.remove([-9,2])
```

i want to use .remove() by using the value of list[2] which is equal to [-9,2] like this

```
 mylist.remove(list[2])
```

but it will give a none value is there any alternative to this because i am looping the value of the index >> list[value changing per loop]. how can i solve this?

this is the loop

```
for p in range (len(mylist)):
      if mylist[p]==startpoint:
        continue
      if mylist[p]==nextpoint:
        continue
      thirdpoint=mylist[p]
      print ('the thirdpoint is:',thirdpoint)
      if orient(startpoint[0],startpoint[1],nextpoint[0],nextpoint[1],thirdpoint[0],thirdpoint[1])>0:
        print ('ok')
        print(mylist)
        print ('the thirdpoint is:',thirdpoint)
        templist=mylist.remove(mylist[p])
        print ('templist is',templist)

        if len(templist)==2:
          print('append nextpoint:',nextpoint)
          ppoint.append(nextpoint)
```

Comment: Please share the loop

Comment: loop through the list backwards

Comment: Hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/45572488/1465553 . Method `pop` is what you may be looking for.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is probably `list.pop(2)` since it removes a list element at a given index.

You could also use the `del` statement, here is the official doc of it: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#the-del-statement

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
templist=mylist.pop(p)
```

instead of

```
templist=mylist.remove(mylist[p])
```

Next time, please copy-paste the complete relevant code.