# Is it PROPER to use del or pop() for simply removing a value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, del

If I want to remove a value from a list in python, is it proper to use `del`or can I just use `pop()` even though it returns the popped value?

I know the difference in how they can be used I just want to know specifically in terms of deleting from a list if I should be using `del` instead of `pop()` for everything.

```
list = [1, 2, 3]
del list[0]
```

vs.

```
list = [1, 2, 3]
list.pop(0)
```

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520492/difference-between-del-remove-and-pop-on-lists

There is no "correct way."
If you need the `value` use pop, else use del.

Comment: What do you mean by "PROPER"? Use whichever one is needed in the situation in which it's being used, otherwise the code will be less clear, possibly less efficient, or could be even be considered misleading

Answer (score 2):

If you do not require the value, `del` is more correct in that it's easier for other readers to infer your intent (i.e. you just want to discard the value instead of using it for something).

However for all purposes that I can think of, they will act identically in your defined scenario. `pop()` obviously returns the value, but you are discarding it immediately.

There may be extremely minor performance / garbage collection benefits to using `del` over `pop()` but I am merely hypothesizing and have nothing to back that up. I am unsure of `del`'s implementation but I can imagine potential implementations that'd be much faster than `pop()` due to not needing to return the removed value. Again, this is extremely minor and meaningless in most circumstances.

Comment: `timeit` reports sensibly similar perfs for both solution (py2.7.x and 3.6.x / linux)