# What is a syntax holdover?

Tags: terminology

I'm relatively new to programming, and I've been reading some stack overflow answers to questions that I've had, and in the comments syntax holdovers are mentioned. I've searched all over for what these are, but I have not found what they are.

Here is a link to where I found this terminology:
[Difference between del, remove and pop on lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520492/difference-between-del-remove-and-pop-on-lists/11520540#comment78976708_11520540)

Comment: Please provide links to where you've seen this phrase mentioned.

Comment: @jaco0646 I added the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Holdover is not a technical term. It has a simple dictionary [definition](https://www.google.com/search?q=holdover).

> a person or thing surviving from an earlier time

However, the word is used incorrectly in the given SO comment. Whereas a holdover is something retained (unchanged) @jxramos uses it to mean something eliminated or modified, which is just the opposite.

The comment appears intended to say, "I thought `del` was a Python 2 keyword that was changed, but it still works in Python 3." And the reply is, "`del` is unchanged, just like `return` etc."