# Deleting a desired list in a 2d list

Tags: python

Say I have a 2d list like this:

`list = [[1, 2, 3], ["a", 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]`

and I want to delete a list that starts with `a`. Here is what I tried:

```
for i in range(0, len(list)):
     if list[i][0] == "a":
          list.pop(i)
```

Here, I am trying to delete a list that starts with `a`. However, it gives me an error saying

> IndexError: list index out of range

I am not sure what the problem is here. It's weird because when I try `print(list[i])`, it prints the matching line, which is `["a", 2, 3].

I am expecting `list = [[1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]` as my final list.

Comment: You changed the length of `list` inside the loop.

Comment: The problem is that you modify your list while iterating over it. Since you delete items from it, then at some point your list is shorter than what `len(list)` used to be.

Comment: Aha, I see... I get it now... Thank you!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a *`list` comprehension*:

```
>>> l = [[1, 2, 3], ["a", 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
>>> new_l = [sublist for sublist in l if sublist[0] != 'a']
>>> new_l
[[1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```

In general, it is not a good idea to name your variables after inbuilts (`list`) since you will shadow those inbuilts.

Also, as others have noted, your original problem was mutating the `list` while iterating over it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `list` comprehension:

```
[x for x in my_list if x[0] != 'a']
```

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that your list length gets shorter as you delete items from it. It will still try to loop at `i = 3`.

You could use a `while` loop instead since it checks every time. Also since you're not using the popped value, use `del`

```
list = [[1, 2, 3], ["a", 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
i = 0
while i < len(list):
    if list[i][0] == "a":
        del list[i]
    else:
        i += 1
```

Related: [Difference between del, remove and pop on lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520492/difference-between-del-remove-and-pop-on-lists/11520540)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) for this!

```
li = [[1, 2, 3], ["a", 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]

#Filter on first element not being equal to a
res = filter(lambda x: x[0] != 'a', li)

#Print the result
print(list(res))
#[[1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about an approach using filter? Also I renamed your list to `l` so you don't overwrite the built-in data type.

```
from operator import itemgetter

f = itemgetter(0)

def test(sublist):
    return f(sublist) != 'a'

list(filter(test, l))

[[1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```