# How to remove last item of a list/array no matter the length

Tags: python, arrays, list

I am trying to remove the last item of a list/array even if there are duplicate items 
EG

`list = ["h","e","l","l","o"," ","t","h","e","r,"e"]`

It would remove the final `"e"` but not the second and ninth `"e"`

I have already tried

`finalSentence.remove([finalSentence[len(finalSentence)-1]])`

However this removes a random letter, I know this is because it is removing a letter rather than item number and python does not know which one to choose so it is a random one that is removed. But I do not know another way to get this to work

Comment: You should be using del to remove by index. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520492/difference-between-del-remove-and-pop-on-lists/11520540

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.remove` removes the *first* occurrence of an item. You could do something like

```
del my_list[len(my_list) - 1]
```

Or simply:

```
del my_list[-1]
```

Or, probably the most idiomatic:

```
my_list.pop()
```

Note, the above methods work in (amortized) constant time, and they modify `my_list` in-place.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `list` as a variable name, as it will probably conflict with the built-in type. But try this:

```
mylist = mylist[:-1]
```

That uses a [slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation) from the beginning of the list up to but not including the last element. If the list is empty, there is no apparent change. If you want an error to be raised, you should use one of the methods of @juanpa.arrivillaga.

Comment: list slicing fails silently, and will return an empty list.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Oops, you are right. I'll edit my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @RoryDaulton it's actually something I forget, because usually I hope things like that will fail. The slicing api for lists is quite "loose", but sometimes it's handy.