# How to remove brackets and content from a list in Python

Tags: python, list

So I have a list from which i want to remove something like a sub list. I don't know how to call it exactly so i couldn't find any results searching for an answer.

```
list = [[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I just want to remove one of those 4 brackets, for example the first one.
Should i use "remove" or "delete" or how do i do that?

```
list = [[0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520492/difference-between-del-remove-and-pop-on-lists/11520540#11520540

Comment: list = list[1:] should remove the first item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `del` it by its index. For example to delete the first one, you can do:

```
my_list = [[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
del my_list[0]
print(my_list)

# output:
[[0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Thank you! Would give you an upvote if i had 15 rep.

Comment: You're welcome. If this answers your question, you can check it as the correct answer, so other people can rely on it

Answer (score 0):

If you know the index which you want to remove `i`:

```
del l[i]
# Or l.pop(i)
```

If you know the value you want to remove `val`:

```
l.remove(val)
```

P.S: Don't use `list` as the name of a variable. It's a name of a builtin class

Comment: Thank you very much! Sorry i can't give upvotes because i dont have enough rep.

Comment: Please note that remove(value) removes the first occurance of value the method encounters. So if the list contains 'xyz' three times, only the first 'xyz' gets removed.