# Most efficient way to remove last element of list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, optimization

With the list: `[-1, 0, 43, 128, 32]`, there are a couple ways of removing the final element.

- `list.pop()`
- `list = list[:-1]` (not recommended?)
- `del list[-1]`
- And probably a couple more...

They would all return `[-1, 0, 43, 128]`, but what's least computationally intensive and does it make a difference? I'm aware of modules like `timeit` which I could use to test this for myself. But I'm wary of uncontrolled variables and my non-expertise could definitely dilute the results. As well, does the best option differ for strings, or floats, or booleans? What about multidimensional lists?

I'm not quite sure how to control and test these variables, so I'd figure I'd ask here to see if there is a general hierarchy.

#### Not a Duplicate of [Difference between del, remove and pop on lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520492/difference-between-del-remove-and-pop-on-lists)

That question explains the differences between methods of deletion, but does not address slicing. It also does not address speed at all. The accepted answer makes vague mentions to efficiency which I can see being part of the solution, but I do not see how it fits with slicing.

Comment: @Mike Is that link saying that `pop`ing is fixed, but slicing scales with the length of the list? As for testing them on average, I might do that in an hour or two if I have time.

Comment: The `timeit` module is designed to do this kind of testing. Have you tried it? The `%timeit` command in an IPython console in particular makes it very easy.

Comment: @Mike, Ah, the second answer. I see it now! Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per mentioned in the [Python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity). Time complexities are as follows:

- Pop last `O(1)`
- Delete Item `O(n)`
- Set Slice `O(k+n)`

### Experimental Study

```
import time

all_t = 0.
for i in range(1000):
    list_ = [i for i in range(100000)]
    start_ = time.time()
    list_.pop()
    all_t += time.time() - start_
print("Average Time for POP is {}".format(all_t/1000.))

all_t = 0.
for i in range(1000):
    list_ = [i for i in range(100000)]
    start_ = time.time()
    del list_[-1]
    all_t += time.time() - start_
print("Average Time for DEL is {}".format(all_t/1000.))

all_t = 0.
for i in range(1000):
    list_ = [i for i in range(100000)]
    start_ = time.time()
    list_ = list_[:-1]
    all_t += time.time() - start_
print("Average Time for SLICE is {}".format(all_t/1000.))
```

### Results

```
Average Time for POP is 7.793903350830078e-07
Average Time for DEL is 9.80854034423828e-07
Average Time for SLICE is 0.0006206443309783935
```

### Summary

`pop()` is the fastest when you do not specify an index.

Comment: @HaleemurAli How is that, there is `e-07` at the end for the first two methods. However, I repeated it after removing the `if-statements` in order to avoid any confusion in case `if-statements` could cause any lagging. Though, it still the same result.

Comment: `del` would be O(n) in general, just as `pop` with an explicit argument would be. `del list[-1]` would not be significantly slower than `pop()`, as your experiment confirms.