# Cannot remove the correct element from the index Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, list, indexing

I am trying to remove a digit from an integer.

My code seems to work except when I input an integer such as 8880888.

For some reason, with an integer above, when removing the index passing the middle number, but it doesn't remove the correct index.

```py
    n = 8880888
    def question(n):
        newlist = [int(x) for x in str(n)] #coverting integer to list
        result = newlist[:]
        y = newlist[5]
        result.remove(y)
    return result
```

When removing the 5th element, it should return  888088.
But instead, I am being returned 880888.

Comment: remove vs. pop vs. del: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11520540/10197418

Answer (score 0):

You are using remove() instead of a del method. If you are looking to remove an element based on an index, your code should look something like:

```
n = [8, 8, 8, 0, 8, 8, 8]

#If you want to remove the 5th element:

del n[5]
```

Please refer to https://www.csestack.org/difference-between-remove-del-pop-python-list/