# Delete value from Dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, user-input

```
players = {
        "nome": "",
        "score": [] 
    }

cancel = False
player_list = []

while (True):
    name = input("Insert player name: ")

    player_list.append({
        "Player Name": name
    })

    cont = input("Do you wish to add another player? (Y/N)")
    if cont == "N":
        break;

print("Player List: ", player_list)

while (True):
    eliminate_player = input("Select player to delete: ")

    player_list.pop({
        "Player Deleted": eliminate_player
    })    

print ("Updated List", player_list)
```

Hello everyone! Im having some trouble deleting an entry from my player list using user input. Im getting the error:'dict' object cannot be interpreted as an integer but I can't seem to find what is wrong because Im using similar method I used to add players and it worked fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: `list.pop(n)` requires an integer to remove the given index from the list. `list.remove(x)` takes an item to find and remove.

Comment: The argument to `.pop()` is an index, not a dictionary.

Comment: What is `jogador_elminado`? Should that be `eliminate_player`?

Comment: The dictionary you use in `.remove()` has to have the same key and value as the dictionary in the list. You can't change `Player Name` to `Player Deleted` when calling `remove()`.

Comment: @Barmar yeah it is, sorry. I translated it from my language and missed it.

Comment: What is the `players` dictionary for? You never use it. Also `cancel`.

Comment: Your questions should say "Delete Value from List"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the right method. `pop(n)` requires an integer (index) to remove the given index from the list. You should use `remove()`.

`remove()` is an inbuilt function that removes a given object from the list. It does not return any value.

```
Syntax:

list_name.remove(obj)
```

Try this:

```
player_list.remove({"Player name": eliminate_player})
```

If the element doesn't exist, it throws `ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list exception`. Wrap it in `try catch` clause in Python.

**Note:**

`remove()` removes the first occurrence of the object from the list.

To remove all occurence of your Player:

```
while (player_list.count({"Player name": eliminate_player})): 
    player_list.remove({"Player name": eliminate_player})
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520492/difference-between-del-remove-and-pop-on-lists/11520540) to understand the difference between pop, remove and del on lists.

> How can I stop it after deleting one player and then show the updated list?

You can use `count` method to break from the while loop:

```
while (True):
    eliminate_player = input("Select player to delete: ")

    di = {"Player name": eliminate_player}
    if player_list.count(di):
        player_list.pop(di)
        break
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `.remove()` rather than `.pop()`. And the dictionary there has to have the same structure as the dictionaries in the list.

```
player_list.remove({"Player name": eliminate_player})
```

Comment: That seems to work. How can I stop it after deleting one player and then show the updated list? Sorry if this is a basic question but Im still learning.

Comment: Do it the same way you enter the players into the list, by checking for `N` and breaking out of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

`pop()` takes an index as argument. You can use `remove()` instead.