# Is there alternative way to do it?

Tags: python

Is there alternative way  to  do it  without using function pop ?

```
Input :a_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

a_list.pop(1)

Output : a_list = [1,3,4,5,6,7]
```

I have tried something but  it says `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable` after my try

Comment: You want to remove the second element from the list?

Comment: Yes, you can add slice before and after the element you want to get rid of (`a_list = a_list[0:1] + a_list[2:]`) or you could `del` the element. Why would you do that like that though, I am not sure. :)

Comment: You can take a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520492/difference-between-del-remove-and-pop-on-lists

Answer (score 1):

You might use `del` keyword in order to do it:

```
a_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
del a_list[1]
print(a_list)  # [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use slicing:

```py
a_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
print(a_list)
a_list = a_list[:1] + a_list[2:]
print(a_list)
```

Comment: Thanks for useful informations. Really appreciate that