# List with empty indexes in python, how to remove?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to remove a position from an empty list, as a simple example that demonstrates or is trying to remove.

```
#Test about fruits

fruits = []

fruits.append('maça')
fruits.append('goiaba')
fruits.append('uva')
fruits.append('pera')
fruits.append('bananna')
fruits[1] = []

print (fruits)
```

Output : `['maça', [], 'uva', 'pera', 'bananna']`

Desired output `['maça', 'uva', 'pera', 'bananna']`

Just remembering that it is a simple example, so I can apply it in a more robust program that I am developing that presents the same problem of having a "position" in the list with a 'null' or empty value in this case.

Comment: [`list(filter(None, fruits))`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter)

Comment: In this case your second element is an empty list, not an empty element, is that actually your case?

Comment: It would probably be a bit more pythonic to use `None` instead of `[]`, or to remove the item from the list immediately instead of using a sentinel.

Comment: `while [] in mylist: mylist.remove([])`

Comment: @JohnGordon it worked perfectly, thank you very much and everyone who responded as well.

Comment: How big is your list and how many empty lists can it contain?

Comment: @JohnGordon highly inefficient.

Comment: Why are you doing `fruits[1] = []`? That is not how you remove an element from a list. To remove an element at an index, you use `del fruits[1]`, for example

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga How so?  I don't see any better way to do it, given that OP said "it is a simple example, so I can apply it in a more robust program"

Comment: @PatrickArtner There is no (direct) list iteration, so I don't understand what problem you are pointing out.

Comment: @JohnGordon because it is a quadratic-time algorithm. You can do it in linear time by using `fruits = [x for x in fruits if x == []]` or the in-place equivalent (probably not necessary)

Answer (score 0):

Use `pop()` to remove an element from a list by its index, rather than assigning an empty value to the index.

```
fruits.pop(1)
```

or `del`

```
del fruits[1]
```

`pop()` allows you to retrieve the value being removed at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> del fruits[1]

See [Difference between del, remove and pop on lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11520492/12575476) for the differences.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't seen the other answer had been edited. The link to the other question is still useful.