# Python: How to return all elements of list in each iteration except for the current element

Tags: python-3.x, list, indexing

My goal is too iterate through a list and return every element in the list except for the current index for each iteration.

For example:

`my_list = [1,2,3]`

should return:

```
>>>[2,3]

>>>[1,3]

>>>[1,2]
```

I've tried creating a for loop that creates a copy of the list, pops the current index from the copy and returns it.

```
my_list = [1,2,3]

for a in my_list:
    the_index = my_list.index(a)
    print(my_list.copy().pop(the_index))
```

which returns

```
>>>1
>>>2
>>>3
```

Any ideas on how to properly implement this?

Comment: This should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520492/difference-between-del-remove-and-pop-on-lists/11520540 (check `del` method).

Comment: So basically just substituting pop with del in your code should do the job (I haven't tried it).

Comment: How important is the ordering of the difference between the original list and current element?

Comment: @jack The ordering is not importent because the end goal is to return the sum of all the list.

Answer (score 5):

The following seems fairly simple:

```
lst = [1,2,3]
[lst[:i] + lst[i+1:] for i in range(len(lst))]
# [[2, 3], [1, 3], [1, 2]]
```

Or for loopy prints:

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
    print(lst[:i] + lst[i+1:])
# [2, 3]
# [1, 3]
# [1, 2]
```

Comment: You beat me by 17 seconds ;-)

Comment: And this is, of course, the simple obvious pythonic solution.

Comment: Yes, very pythonic. Would you be able to clarify why you used range and passed the length of the list inside of it? I would expect that would be equal to simply saying range(3), since there are three elements inside the list. This is obviously not the case. I would like to better understand whats going on here.

Answer (score 1):

```
my_list = [1,2,3]
for a in my_list:
    the_index = my_list[my_list.index(a)]
    z=my_list.copy()
    z.pop(the_index-1)
    print(z)
```

when you are printing copy() with pop() operation it will retrun the poped element so seprate the copy and pop() operation.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification on why the statements have to separate. Very informative

Answer (score 0):

The above problem can be solved using this:

```
my_list = [1,2,3]
for b in my_list:
    my_list.remove(b)
    print(my_list)
    my_list.append(b)
    my_list.sort()
```