# Adding multiple names to list

Tags: python, list

How do I append a list based on user input? I have made a menu and used ifelif statements. When running the script I select "2" to add a name to the list, after inputting the name, I press "1" to display the list. No matter how many names I add I am only able too to view the last inputted name.

```
**menu = """


 mylist = ['Nick', 'Robert', 'Deondre,']
while True:
selection = input(menu).strip()
if selection == "0":
    print("Thank you for using guest list manager.")
    break
elif selection == "1":
    print("List of guests.\n")
    print(mylist)
elif selection == "2":
    mylist = input('Please enter a name to be added: ') 
elif selection == "3":
    mylist = input("Please enter a name to be deleted: ")
    mylist.append(mylist)
else:
    print("Please select 0, 1, 2, or 3")**
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your original list. Use a separate variable for saving input and then append it to your original list.

Instead of this:

```py
elif selection == "2":
    # You are replacing your list
    mylist = input('Please enter a name to be added: ')
```

Write this:

```py
elif selection == "2":
    # Save input in a variable
    new_name = input('Please enter a name to be added: ')
    # Append it at the end
    mylist.append(new_name)
```

Similarly for selection 3 (deletion), you need to save the input in a variable and use that to delete element from the list. `list.append()` is for adding element(s) at the end of a list, not for deletion. For deletion you can use `list.remove()` instead.

```py
elif selection == "3":
    # Save input in a variable
    name_to_be_deleted = input("Please enter a name to be deleted: ")
    # Save input in a variable
    mylist.remove(name_to_be_deleted)
```

**Reference:** [SO answer comparing deletion methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11520540/8080186)