# How to change the index of a list in python. I am getting rid of the first value, but the index still stays the same

Tags: python, list

EG.

```py
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]

list1[0] = None
```

How do I get the list to now start at 2 (make the index of 2 = list1[0]) because when I call list1[0] after doing this I get a blank output.

Comment: How are you getting rid of element at index 1?

Comment: Instead of `list1[0] = None` do `del list1[0]`

Answer (score 1):

Here' how to remove the first item using slicing

```
>>> list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> list1 = list1[1:]
>>> list1[0]
2
```

Or you can use `list.pop(0)`

```
>>> item = list1.pop(0)
>>> item
2
>>> list1[0]
3
```

Comment: I'd just like to add a link for an explenation about the notation from another post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation

Comment: [small benchmark](https://tio.run/##PY3NCsIwEITvfYq5lCRSSmtBpNAnKUUiphowPyTrwaePSQPOaWaYb9d/6eXsdPUhpT04A9JGaYI23gVCUF5JaprdBdygLYK0T8UnMTfIKnUsNZNYINdx3lgH9lDvHIbDy947zwdx@HUetzzkglW@iHJhtOX1FY9dPZZxnDAOWRm1H3NXYTmiEH/WB22Js/bSn3eYCIYWnAqnJtEh1mVdiZR@)

Answer (score 0):

```py
print(list1)  # [1, 2, 3, 4]
list1.pop(0)
print(list1)  # [2, 3, 4]
print(list1[0])
```

===
Will print the following output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[2, 3, 4]
2
```

Answer (score -1):

Otherwise you can `del(index)` or `pop(index)` a item with a certain index. Del just deletes the item from the list, pop deletes the item from the list and returns it. Have a look here: [Difference between del, remove, and pop on lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520492/difference-between-del-remove-and-pop-on-lists)

Comment: You can also `del` slices.