# Python can't remove a values index in a list when I am able to print the same value using its index

Tags: python, list

I am trying to remove a value from the list but python seems to not be able to even though I am able to print it. The value is 5 which you will be able to see in the error but when I try to remove the same value it throws me an error message.

The "`sequence.remove(e+1)`" line should be the same value as "`print(sequence[e+1])`" right?

code:

```
def solution(sequence):
    decisionList = []
    ultDec = bool
    def comparing():
        i = 0
        decisionList.clear()
        for i in range(len(sequence)-1):
            num1 = i
            num2 = i + 1
            if sequence[num1] < sequence[num2]:
                decisionList.append("bigger")
            if sequence[num1] > sequence[num2]:
                decisionList.append("smaller")
            if sequence[num1] == sequence[num2]:
                decisionList.append("equal")
        findIrregular()
        
    repeated = 0
    
    def findIrregular():
        nonlocal repeated
        ultDec = ""
        e = 0
        for e in range(len(decisionList)):
            
            val1 = e
            
            if decisionList[val1] == "smaller":
                if repeated < 1:
                    print(sequence[e+1], "is the value im trying to remove")
                    sequence.remove(e+1)
                    repeated = repeated + 1
                    comparing()
                if repeated >= 1:
                    return False
                    
            elif decisionList[val1] == "equal":
                if repeated < 1:
                    sequence.remove(e + 1)
                    repeated = repeated + 1
                    comparing()
                if repeated >= 1:
                    return False
                    
            elif decisionList[val1] == "bigger":
                pass
            
        return True
    comparing()
    return findIrregular()
solution([3, 6, 5, 8, 10, 20, 15])
```

error:
So as you can see "`5 is the value im trying to remove`" is what causes the error

```
5 is the value im trying to remove
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 46, in <module>
File "<string>", line 44, in solution
  File "<string>", line 16, in comparing
  File "<string>", line 29, in findIrregular
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Comment: If the answer helped you then click on tick mark to accept it :)

Answer (score 2):

list.remove removes the given member of the list, for example, if we have a list like [1, 2, 5] and we use .remove(5) our list will be [1, 2].
If you want to remove a member by its index, try .pop(i)

Comment: You can use del too.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520492/difference-between-del-remove-and-pop-on-lists

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
 sequence.remove(sequence[e+1])
```

or

```
 sequence.pop(e+1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, `remove` takes the item/value you want to remove. If you want to remove by index then use `.pop(index)`

Instead of this:

```
sequence.remove(e+1)
```

Use:

```
sequence.pop(e+1)
```