# How can i remove ONLY 1 of the duplicate values from a list?

Tags: python

i want to extract only 1 of the duplicate items in a list to a different empty list (also randomly selected)
lets say the list is

```
list = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]
extracted_list = []
#i have tried desperately to find a way to turn the list to
#example:
list = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]
extracted_list = [1]
#what i was trying to do was this:
import random
card_list = [11, 11, 11, 11, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10,]
player = []
dealer = []
popped = [] 
choice = random.choice(card_list)
popped = card_list.pop(choice)
player.append(popped)
print(player)
print(card_list)
```

when i use this piece of code it removes only 1 duplicate but can ONLY select 11, 2 or 3 for some reason

i want to use pop() in order to extract one of the random duplicate items into another list
can anyone help me?

Comment: What if there are no duplicates ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between del, remove, and pop on lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520492/difference-between-del-remove-and-pop-on-lists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.pop()` removes by index, not by value. You'll want `list.remove()` with the chosen value (or, equivalently, `index = card_list.index(choice); card_list.pop(index)` but that's more work for you).

```
choice = random.choice(card_list)
card_list.remove(choice)
```

In other words,

```
import random

card_list = [
    1,
    1,
    1,
    2,
    2,
    3,
    4,
]

print("initial", card_list)
player = []
while card_list:
    choice = random.choice(card_list)
    card_list.remove(choice)
    player.append(choice)
    print(player, "remaining:", card_list)
```

prints out e.g.

```
initial: [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4]
[4] remaining: [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
[4, 1] remaining: [1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
[4, 1, 2] remaining: [1, 1, 2, 3]
[4, 1, 2, 3] remaining: [1, 1, 2]
[4, 1, 2, 3, 1] remaining: [1, 2]
[4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2] remaining: [1]
[4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1] remaining: []
```

Or, with a `card_list` of strings (because numbers and list indices could be confusable):

```
initial: ['cat', 'cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog', 'bird', 'fish']
['cat'] remaining: ['cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog', 'bird', 'fish']
['cat', 'bird'] remaining: ['cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog', 'fish']
['cat', 'bird', 'cat'] remaining: ['cat', 'dog', 'dog', 'fish']
['cat', 'bird', 'cat', 'cat'] remaining: ['dog', 'dog', 'fish']
['cat', 'bird', 'cat', 'cat', 'fish'] remaining: ['dog', 'dog']
['cat', 'bird', 'cat', 'cat', 'fish', 'dog'] remaining: ['dog']
['cat', 'bird', 'cat', 'cat', 'fish', 'dog', 'dog'] remaining: []
```

Comment: but can i add the removed value to another list with .remove() ?

Comment: You already have the removed value; it's `choice`.

Comment: but lets say can i do removed_value = card_list.remove(choice) and use the removed_value elsewhere?

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: @Frqim `.remove` simply returns `None`. But that's fine, **you already pass that as an argument** so you already have access to that value

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remove a random card using `.pop()` you have a few ways to do this. The example below would be as if with each shuffle of cards you removed one from the list of cards.

```
import random

card_list = [11, 11, 11, 11, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10,]
player = []

random.shuffle(card_list)

while card_list:
    player.append(card_list.pop())
    print("Player:", player)
    print("Remaining Cards:", card_list)
```

Comment: Why bother shuffling it on each iteration? The result would be the same if you shuffled it only once.

Comment: You are right I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
import random

hand = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3]

def remove_a_duplicate(hand):
    chosen = None
    if hand:
        counter = Counter(hand)
        one_each = Counter(set(hand))
        multiple = counter - one_each
        if multiple:
            chosen = random.choice(list(multiple.keys()))
            hand.remove(chosen)
    return hand, chosen

for i in range(7):
    hand, removed = remove_a_duplicate(hand)
    print(hand, removed)
```

Outputs:

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3] 1
[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3] 1
[1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3] 1
[1, 2, 2, 2, 3] 2
[1, 2, 2, 3] 2
[1, 2, 3] 2
[1, 2, 3] None
```

I used the `collections.Counter` to count the card values then subtracted the count of unique values. The resulting `multiple` contains only values which are present at least 2 times. I then choose a random one of these which gets removed from the original hand.
Whenever there is an empty hand, or no duplicated, the returned second value will be `None` which you can check after calling this function.

Answer (score 0):

Use `random.randrange(len(card_list))` or `random.randint(0,len(card_list)-1)` to get the index to `pop`:

```
import random
card_list = [11, 11, 11, 11, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10,]
player = []
dealer = []
choice = random.randrange(len(card_list))
popped = card_list.pop(choice)
player.append(popped)
print(player)
print(card_list)
```

Comment: i tried this but for some reason it only returned 11, 2 and 3. I must have tried it at least 100 times

Answer (score -1):

The first thing to do is to make a list of the duplicated values. Then you can select one of those values (assuming there is at least one duplicate) then pop that from the original list. Something like this:

```
import random

_list = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]

dups = [n for n in set(_list) if _list.count(n) > 1]

new_list = [_list.pop(random.choice(dups))] if dups else []

print(_list)
print(new_list)
```