# Conditionally format string

Tags: python, string, format

Consider following code

```
', '.join(['{} <{}> ({})'.format(user.nickname, user.email, user.employee_id)
                     for user in referrers])
```

Now I'd like to skip `()` and empty space when employee_id doesn't exist.

```
referrer_strs = []
for user in referrers:
    if user.employee_id is None:
        referrer_strs.append('{} <{}>'.format(user.nickname, user.email))
    else:
        referrer_strs.append('{} <{}> ({})'.format(user.nickname, user.email, user.employee_id))

return ', '.join(referrer_strs)
```

I could convert it to for comprehension, but is there a more pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: This code looks good. It is readable. Don't change it.

Comment: I know's it's readable, but I've wondering if there is some string format magic e.g. '{} <{}>{? ()}'

Comment: Try this https://pyformat.info/ . Maybe you find something. But I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

The code is now more fun =P

You can use the "pseudo-ternary operator", if you want to do everything in just one line

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, nickname, email, employee_id=None):
        self.nickname = nickname
        self.email = email
        self.employee_id = employee_id

referrers = [
    User('macabeus', 'macabeus@gmail.com', 1),
    User('joão', 'joao@gmail.com'),
    User('josé', 'jose@gmail.com', 3)
]

print(
    ', '.join(
        ['{} <{}>{}'.format(user.nickname, user.email, ('', ' ({})'.format(user.employee_id))[user.employee_id is not None])
                     for user in referrers]
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this [conditional list indices removal SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163406/python-delete-all-list-indices-meeting-a-certain-condition), try adding an if logic:

```
', '.join(['{} <{}> ({})'.format(user.nickname, user.email, user.employee_id)
                     for user in referrers if not (user.employee_id is None)])
```